# Removing specific tag and text - cheeriojs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

i am trying to remove a very specific tag and text inside the html file i am scraping. Does anyone have any idea how i can search and remove this specific tag and text all together?

`<p class="align-left">&#xA0; Scheduled Arrival Time</p>`

Comment: take a look at this please :D https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3542461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to replace a specific element with its content.
feel free to edit the regex to match your needs. its selecting any p tag with 'align-left' class .

```js
var pattern = /<(p)\s*class\s*=\s*['\"]\s*align-left\s*['\"]\s*[^<]*<\/\1\s*>/g;
var content = "this is<p class=\"align-left\">&#xA0; Scheduled Arrival Time</p> a line !";
content = content.replace(pattern, "");
console.log(content);
```

if you need to check if a text exists in a specific tag , you can use this :

```js
var pattern = /<(p)\s*class\s*=\s*['\"]\s*align-left\s*['\"]\s*>[^<]*(Arrival Time)[^<]*<\/\1\s*>/g;
var content = "this is<p class=\"align-left\">&#xA0; Scheduled Arrival Time</p> a line !";
var test2 = "im not <p class=\"align-left\">&#xA0; Scheduled</p> a line !";
content = content.replace(pattern, "");
console.log(content);
console.log(test2);
```