# How to Remove p tag on api while fetching the data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to remove all html tag from API(description section) while fetching the data i go html tag. I have attached the screenshot of the output, please have a look.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066507/removing-specific-tag-and-text-cheeriojs

Comment: i have tried but that solution does not worked for me. can you suggest other solution

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
    npm i react-html-parser
   ```
2. ```
   install import parse from "html-react-parser";
   ```
3. ```
   <p>{parse(description.substring(0, 299))}</p>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the incoming HTML from the API response to display as HTML by using this:

```
  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blog }} ></span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
    blogs = blogs.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
    setBlog(blogs)
```

Replacing all tags